# How to arrange the datas to display in array by given string of days in java?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

```
String[] daysList = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
```

Now given input string is

```
String getRoutePlanDay = "Thu";
```

So the output should be

```
output: "Thu", "Fri","Sat","Mon" ,"Tue","Wed".
```

Similarly for eg: If given string is

```
String getRoutePlanDay = "Fri";

 Expected output: "Fri","Sat","Mon" ,"Tue","Wed","Thu"
```

So how to sort the array list by starting of the given input string.

```
 List<String> asSet = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(daysList));
  //but i couldn't figure out how to use the getRoutePlanDay by comparing with the list and arranging it and storing in string array?
```

Comment: If you only want to print, juste iterate from index and modulo the size

Comment: I don't want to print. I just need to store in  string array..

Comment: Share your tries , it show no efforts here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collections.rotate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-) will do that you want

```
String[] daysArr = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };
List<String> daysList = Arrays.asList(daysArr);
String input = "Fri";
int index = daysList.indexOf(input);
if (index > 0) {
    Collections.rotate(daysList, -index);
}
System.out.println(daysList);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm would be:

- Create a new array of the same length as the old one
- Find the index of your starting day
- Copy the array part from the starting day till the end to the new array
- Copy the array part from index 0 to the starting day - 1 to the new array

Done.

You can use `System.arraycopy` to copy parts of an array to another.

Answer (score 0):

If you will see following code 
    Get the index of your object from where you want to start
    then get sublist from index to size of original list and add it to new list.
    again get sublist from startindex to **getRoutePlanDay**  for remaining list and add it to the new list you will get your desired output

```
            ArrayList<String> dayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            dayList.add("Mon");
            dayList.add("Tue");
            dayList.add("Wed");
            dayList.add("Thu");
            dayList.add("Fri");
            dayList.add("Sat");
            String getRoutePlanDay = "Fri";
            int index = dayList.indexOf(getRoutePlanDay);
            List<String> newList = dayList.subList(index, dayList.size());
            newList.addAll(dayList.subList(0, index));
            System.out.println(newList);
```

Tested for your inputs and working on my side

Answer (score 0):

This code might do :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    
    String[] daysList = {"Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"};
    int count = daysList.length;
    int ipos = 0,j=1,k=0;
    int flag = 1;
    while (k<count){
        //Getting the input from command line argument
        if (daysList[k].equals(args[0])){
            ipos = k;
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }else{
            flag = 0;
            k++;
        }            
    }

    j = ipos;
    //getting the output route
    if (flag == 1) {
       int count2 = 0;
       while (j<=count){
       
            // output[count2] = daysList[j];
            System.out.print(daysList[j] + ",");
            count2 = count2 + 1;
            j = j + 1;
            if (count2 < 6){
                j = j % 6;    
            }else{
                break;
            }           
        }  
    }else{
        System.out.println("The day you enter is not present in the daylist");
    }   
}
```